# How could I share a common setup fixture for spec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to use these fixture for many spec files.

Currently, I have to COPY and PASTE following snippet among every SPEC scripts. How could I do it in a better way. Thanks

```
  before(:all) do
    @airline = FG.create(:airline)
    @airports = AIRPORTS.collect{|airport| FG.create(:airport, code: airport)}
    @flight = FG.create(:flight, from_airport: @airports[0], to_airport: @airports[3])
    @sku = FG.create(:flight_sku, flight: @flight)
    @fares = CABIN_TYPE.collect do |cabin|
      FG.create(:flight_sku_fare,
                flight_sku: @sku,
                cabin_class: cabin,
                price: Faker::Number.between(1500, 18000))
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `shared_context`: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/example-groups/shared-context.

```
RSpec.shared_context "create airlines" do

  before(:all) do
    @airline = FG.create(:airline)
    @airports = AIRPORTS.collect{|airport| FG.create(:airport, code: airport)}
    @flight = FG.create(:flight, from_airport: @airports[0], to_airport: @airports[3])
    @sku = FG.create(:flight_sku, flight: @flight)
    @fares = CABIN_TYPE.collect do |cabin|
      FG.create(:flight_sku_fare,
                flight_sku: @sku,
                cabin_class: cabin,
                price: Faker::Number.between(1500, 18000))
    end
  end
end
```

In your spec

```
describe "My test" do
  include_context "create airlines"
end
```